# SignalR works only locally

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a project using ASP.NET Core with SignalR core. When I test locally on IIS server on Windows it works but when I deploy on Linux server with Kestrel I have an error:

> can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   was://lalala/chat?id=someid.

I used [this manual](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/).

Comment: Can you provide more details about your Linux server infrastructure?

Comment: @Ignas, linux ubuntu 16.04, kestrel, nginx as proxy server to redirect on localhost where the kestrel works, mysql, dotnet core 2. But I tried to check a test project with SignalR on free hosting with IIS and windows and the project didn't work (on a local machine all was good)

Comment: @Ignas new information. When I set in visual studio in project settings/debug Environment value release instead of development it doesn't work even locally...

Comment: and then I found out that my test project doesn't work with value release in project properties and my main project works well (on the local machine)

Comment: Created a test project on asp.net standart with signalr and everything works well on a server...

Comment: Created test asp.net core project and signalr works well on a windows server (but when I tried to remove signalr from my main project and add this simple functionality that works in test project it still doesn't work. What can prevent?)

Comment: it seems that signalr doesn't work because of nginx. When I request to my app from the server via localhost everything is fine. But when I request to the app from another machine via alias the connection is not established

Comment: You have to configure any proxy you're behind to allow websockets through